# html5 local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

so I'm trying to figure out where the client side db gets stored actually. If I create something like this

```
    var mcTasks = {};
    mcTasks.webdb = {};

    //OPENING THE DATABASE
    mcTasks.webdb.db = null;
    mcTasks.webdb.open = function() {
    var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    mcTasks.webdb.db = openDatabase('todo', '1.0', 'todo manager', dbSize);
    }
```

Where does this get stored? in cache? and if so that means that if I clear the cache the info gets lost right?

I'm trying to figure out which solution is better sqlLite or window.localStorage, any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets stored in a location on the client machine, as a persistent file.

This is *separate* from the cache, so clearing the cache shouldn't have an effect on the stored data.

Where exactly the file is stored depends on the implementation.

Comment: awesome, so I have to define the file or it automatically gets generated? Is there anything I have to code in order to exclude the deletion of the cache in order to not affect this file or it should never affect the file no matter what? thanks!

Comment: The file gets stored per domain - you don't need to specify a name. You don't need to worry about cache, this is totally separate. I suggest reading the draft [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).